# Is it possible to create a custom class that utilizes API-specific XML tags?

Tags: android, xml

I am attempting to create a drawable in xml using a `Drawable` subclass (in this case [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html)) to use as a background in a `View`, but the drawable does not calculate and display its layers the way I had intended.  With help from this forum I have found the particular lines of source code that are causing my issue and feel I can very easily create a subclass or change the code or to do what I want.

My question is, assuming I make a new class with no unintended side-effects and I will never need access the old functionality, is it possible to use the new `Drawable` with the [original `Drawable`'s xml tag structure](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) (ex. `layer-list`) to create my updated drawable in the same way?

For example, replace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/resource_name"
        android:drawable=drawable/drawable_resource" />

</layer-list>
```

with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package.MyLayerDrawable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/resource_name"
        android:drawable=drawable/drawable_resource" />

</package.MyLayerDrawable>
```

Comment: I would think so, I know that it works that way if you create your own View object. But I've never tried personally so I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: I was pretty sure it is not as simple as just subclassing LayerDrawable, which I already tested just to make sure. There doesn't seem to be any documentation about it on the android website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Custom drawables are not allowed from XML, mostly for security reasons. XML 
>   drawables can be loaded as resources by other processes (including Launcher 
>   or the system process) and it would be a terrible idea to run random 3rd 
>   party code in these processes.

Very unfortunately, instead of properly sandboxing custom drawables they decided to completely disallow it.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/825a5d8b401d3332

Answer (score 0):

like this? :

```
 package your.packepage;

 public class RemoteImageView extends ImageView {
     ....
 }

 <your.packpage.RemoteImageView 
 android:id="@+id/img_id" 
 android:layout_width="10dp" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: My goal is to subclass `LayerDrawable`, as opposed to a `View`. In the code above, for example, I would also like to directly use the `item` tag in the new subclass xml.